# How to make a script run at boot time?

Tags: boot, bash, scripts

I have the following shell script code that is not running at boot time.

The `boot.sh` file is located in `/home/icrs/boot.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/icrs/manipulator_proj
source devel/setup.bash 
xterm -hold -e "roscore" &
//xterm -hold -e "cd ~/manipulator_proj/ && ls && catkin_make"  
//xterm -hold -e "cd ~/manipulator_proj/ && source devel/setup.bash"
xterm -hold -e "cd ~/manipulator_proj/ && rosrun dynamixel_control  dynamixel_control"
xterm -hold -e "cd ~/manipulator_proj/ && rosrun dynamixel_control ik"
xterm -hold -e "cd ~/manipulator_proj/ && rosrun dynamixel_control server_node"
```

In terminal it's running fine and excuting, but at boot time it's not running. I placed this file in `/etc/rc.local`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/home/icrs/boot.sh:
exit 0
```

Kindly suggest us any solution for this issue.

Comment: Your script runs graphical programs, so I suppose you want it to be rather started on *login* – see the linked question for how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Seems your script should run when you log in to X.
Have a look under System > Preferences > Startup Applications.

Alternatively you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the `gnome-session-properties` command. Add your script here.